# Pandas Python - Create dummy variables for multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column that indicates which hour of the day a particular action was performed.  So df['hour'] is many rows each with a value from 0 to 23.

I am trying to create dummy variables for things like 'is_morning', for example:
if df['hour'] >= 5 and < 12 then return 1, else return 0

A for loop doesn't work given the size of the data set, and I've tried some other stuff like
df['is_morning'] = df['hour'] >= 5 and < 12

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do:

```
df['is_morning'] = (df['hour'] >= 5) & (df['hour'] < 12)
```

i.e. wrap each condition in parentheses, and use `&`, which is an `and` operation that works across the whole vector/column.

Comment: whoa, super simple, thanks Marius. thought I had tried this but I guess I messed up somewhere.

Comment: Is there a clean way to get integers (0, 1) and ensure when `df.hour` is NaN then `df.is_morning` is also NaN?